# Columns with unequal length and headers buried within these columns

Tags: python, r, data-cleaning

I have some data where every second column corresponds to a specific time, each time period have respectively 'buy' and 'sell' positions, and each of these position have two factors (as seen below). However the columns have unequal lengths, and so the 'sell' options start at different rows (buried among the values).

```
time, time1, time,  time2,  time, time3
buy,       , buy,        ,  buy,    
factor1,  1, factor1,    2, factor1,  3
factor2,  4, factor2,    5, factor2,  6
factor1,  7, factor1,    8, factor1,  9
factor2, 10, factor2,   11, factor2, 12
factor1, 13, sell,        , factor1, 14
factor2, 15, factor1,   16, factor2, 17
sell,      , factor2,   18, factor1, 19
factor1, 20, ,            , factor2, 21,
factor2, 22, ,            , sell,     
,          , ,            , factor1, 23
,          , ,            , factor2, 24
,          , ,            , factor1, 25
,          , ,            , factor2, 26
```

Ultimately, I would like I table structured like below.

```
time,   position,   factor,     value
time1,  buy,        factor1,    1
time1,  buy,        factor2,    4
time1,  buy,        factor1,    7
time1,  buy,        factor2,    10
time1,  buy,        factor1,    13
time1,  buy,        factor2,    15
time1,  sell,       factor1,    20
time1,  sell,       factor2,    22
time2,  buy,        factor1,    2
time2,  buy,        factor2,    5
time2,  buy,        factor1,    8
time2,  buy,        factor2,    11
time2,  sell,       factor1,    16
time2,  sell,       factor2,    18
time3,  buy,        factor1,    3
time3,  buy,        factor2,    6
time3,  buy,        factor1,    9
time3,  buy,        factor2,    12
time3,  buy,        factor1,    14
time3,  buy,        factor2,    17
time3,  buy,        factor1,    19
time3,  buy,        factor2,    21
time3,  sell,       factor1,    23
time3,  sell,       factor2,    24
time3,  sell,       factor1,    25
time3,  sell,       factor2,    26
```

I am able to extract the indices and then create respectively 'buy' and 'sell' list in R. But I am unsure whether this is the easiest approach (I have many such files, and would prefer a fast automatic method). I am also open to making the transformation i Python, rather than R.

```
# For each column find the index of buy, sell (and the corresponding empty cell)
idx = apply(data, 2, function(x) which(x %in% c("buy","sell",""))[1:3] )
# NA indicates that the empty cell is the last
idx[is.na(idx)] = nrow(data)

i = 0
buy = list( apply(idx, 2, function(x) {
  i <<- i+1
  data[seq(x[1]+1,x[2]),i]
}) )
i = 0
sell = list( apply(idx, 2, function(x) {
  i <<- i+1
  data[seq(x[2]+1,x[3]),i]
}) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decidd to combine the 3 sets of 2 columns first in one long format data set. Then fill in the position column by last known value carried forward (`tidyr::fill`), and filter out the rubbish, by filtering on the column value.

Here is the working example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

str <- "
time, time1, time,  time2,  time, time3
buy,       , buy,        ,  buy,    
factor1,  1, factor1,    2, factor1,  3
factor2,  4, factor2,    5, factor2,  6
factor1,  7, factor1,    8, factor1,  9
factor2, 10, factor2,   11, factor2, 12
factor1, 13, sell,        , factor1, 14
factor2, 15, factor1,   16, factor2, 17
sell,      , factor2,   18, factor1, 19
factor1, 20, ,            , factor2, 21,
factor2, 22, ,            , sell,     
,          , ,            , factor1, 23
,          , ,            , factor2, 24
,          , ,            , factor1, 25
,          , ,            , factor2, 26
"

strfile <- textConnection(str)

raw <- read.table(strfile, header = F, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = F)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dt <- do.call(rbind, lapply(1:3, function(x) {
  p <- raw[,c(x*2-1,x*2)]
  names(p) <- c('factor', 'value')
  p$time <- x
  p
  })
)

dt %>% 
  mutate(position = if_else(trimws(factor) %in% c('buy','sell'),as.character(factor),as.character(NA)),
         value = as.numeric(value)) %>%
  fill(position) %>% filter(!is.na(value))
```

Result:

```
factor value time position
1   factor1     1    1      buy
2   factor2     4    1      buy
3   factor1     7    1      buy
4   factor2    10    1      buy
5   factor1    13    1      buy
6   factor2    15    1      buy
7   factor1    20    1     sell
8   factor2    22    1     sell
9   factor1     2    2      buy
10  factor2     5    2      buy
11  factor1     8    2      buy
12  factor2    11    2      buy
13  factor1    16    2     sell
14  factor2    18    2     sell
15  factor1     3    3      buy
16  factor2     6    3      buy
17  factor1     9    3      buy
18  factor2    12    3      buy
19  factor1    14    3      buy
20  factor2    17    3      buy
21  factor1    19    3      buy
22  factor2    21    3      buy
23  factor1    23    3     sell
24  factor2    24    3     sell
25  factor1    25    3     sell
26  factor2    26    3     sell
```